# Android - How to create divider for ListView with rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to give my `ListView` rounded corners and some padding. Here is my style:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
  <corners android:radius="10px"/>
  <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

But when I create a divider its width is not from one end to the other but looks like this:

[image]

I create the divider like this:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/livList"
                      ...
                      android:divider="@color/bordeaux"
                      android:dividerHeight="1px" />
```

Any ideas how to tell the divider to strech from one end to the other?

Comment: adding screenshot would be better

Comment: I tried to answer your question. Frankly your question is just not clear. Please edit so that we waste less time trying to understand it.

Comment: Sorry, but have a look at the screenshot. There is a white space between the red line and the border of the `ListView`. I need the divider to strech over the whole width of the ListView... thats all.

Comment: If that so, why are you adding padding on your drawable?

Comment: So you mean giving the SubItems a padding and not the container?

Comment: @Android-Developer: So easy and so great :) If you post an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add an answer with the solutions from comments if anybody else have the same problem.If you want your divider to fit the whole `ListView` just remove `paddings` set in your `drawable` in xml. And just another thing: while trying to style `ListView` items, you need to 'work' on xml file which contains views which you are using to populate current item.

Answer (score 0):

Dude you've entered right, left paddings as 5dp. Remove left & right paddings or make them 0dp